# CLOSE_WAIT socket memory implications

Tags: c++, c, sockets, unix

I'm working on a big server in C++ where we provide service to multiple users. I noticed recently that after some cases in my code, sockets are not closed properly and we have thousands of them in the state CLOSE_WAIT. I read what this mean

> CLOSE_WAIT  Indicates that the server has received the first FIN
>   signal from the client and the connection is in the process of being
>   closed
>
> So this essentially means that his is a state where socket is waiting
>   for the application to execute close()
>
> A socket can be in CLOSE_WAIT state indefinitely until the application
>   closes it.  Faulty scenarios would be like filedescriptor leak, server
>   not being execute close() on socket leading to pile up of close_wait
>   sockets

I'm starting to search where is my bug because it's clear that we are not closing properly these sockets.

What implies for my program memory having all these sockets in CLOSE_WAIT state? I noticed that when I have a lot of these sockets the process start to consume a lot of memory (4GB). Which implications in relation with memory have this? Maybe this memory leak is not related with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: When a TCP socket is being closed nicely by the peer (i.e. when your local socket is in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state) it will be marked as *readable*. If you then attempt to read from it, the `read` call will return `0` meaning "socket closed nicely by peer". That in turn means you should `close` the socket on your side. You need to check that your code handles this case properly.

Comment: Yes, If we close them properly I understand that socket will be moved to TIME_WAIT state and can be reused. My question is, having these sockets in CLOSE_WAIT can lead to a memory leak which I'm having? or they are different problems? Thanks

Comment: Regarding the state-change, not quite. See e.g. [this state diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#/media/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed_new.svg) for more information. Regarding your worry about leaks, yes it is. If the socket is not closed it will be a resource leak. Memory for buffers associated with the socket will not be released, and the socket itself will continue to take up a slot in the descriptor table for the process.